# Writing stream data in map back to a List

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a treemap with information. I can foreach through it and pick the fields I want to print or just create a class from. But I can't figure out the conversion from that and get it into a List<>

Ideally I would like to have it returned as

```
List<AssetMinuteTotals> listATM = assetsList.stream() ..
```

Or in another form that makes the listATM contain the AssetMinuteTotals list.
I can't use collect since that is not part of TreeMap. As you can see below I have tried list.add. But that syntax is apparently not correct.

```
assetsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
Function.identity(), ()->new TreeMap<>(group),
Collectors.summarizingDouble(Asset::getPrice)))
.forEach((a,p)-> new AssetMinuteTotals(a.getPaper(), p.getAverage(), 
                    (long)a.getTradeMinutesSinceMidnight(), p.getCount()));
```

The `group` is defined this way:

```
Comparator<Asset> group=Comparator.comparing(Asset::getPaper)
    .thenComparing(Asset::getTradeMinutesSinceMidnight);
```

I have tried with this. But that will not compile.

```
assetsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
Function.identity(), ()->new TreeMap<>(group),
Collectors.summarizingDouble(Asset::getPrice)))
.forEach((a,p)-> new AssetMinuteTotals(a.getPaper(), p.getAverage(), 
                    (long)a.getTradeMinutesSinceMidnight(), p.getCount()) -> listAMT.add(e);
```

I can solve this by passing the list as an argument. But that seems very ugly since I have to implement that in the constructor of the AssetMinuteTotals class

```
assetsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
Function.identity(), ()->new TreeMap<>(group),
Collectors.summarizingDouble(Asset::getPrice)))
.forEach((a,p)-> new AssetMinuteTotals(a.getPaper(), p.getAverage(), 
                    (long)a.getTradeMinutesSinceMidnight(), p.getCount(), listAMT));
```

Comment: It would be great with a suggestion on how to implement it instead.

Comment: It would be great if you did a thorough attempt first. What is `e`? Why are you surprised that a code fragment not even having balanced parentheses does not compile? If you were about writing a `for` loop rather than lambda expressions, would you really consider moving the adding into the object’s constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you want to create a new stream from the `Map` and collect it:

```
List<AssetMinuteTotals> result = assetsList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        () -> new TreeMap<>(group),
                        Collectors.summarizingDouble(Asset::getPrice)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new AssetMinuteTotals(entry.getKey().getPaper(),
                entry.getValue().getAverage(), 
                (long) entry.getKey().getTradeMinutesSinceMidnight(),
                entry.getValue().getCount()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Though I would assign it to the intermediate variable as this looks more clean for me:

```
TreeMap<Asset, DoubleSummaryStatistics> map = assetsList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        () -> new TreeMap<>(group),
                        Collectors.summarizingDouble(Asset::getPrice)));
List<AssetMinuteTotals> result = map
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new AssetMinuteTotals(entry.getKey().getPaper(),
                entry.getValue().getAverage(), 
                (long) entry.getKey().getTradeMinutesSinceMidnight(),
                entry.getValue().getCount()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Both are great solutions. I just didn't know how to continue from one stream to the next.